# Can anyone tell me why I cant run the ANOVA in my R script?

Tags: r

I tried running this one-way repeated measures ANOVA on my data and I keep getting the error message telling me that none of the rows in my dataframe can be identified by a unique combination of keys, even though all of the rows in the dataframe are unique in some regard.

The code of the script:

```
#tidyverse and ggpubr are some easy visualization libraries I saw online, idk if we really need them
#rstatix is for the anova test

install.packages('rstatix')
install.packages('ggpubr')
install.packages('readxl')
install.packages('magrittr')
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
library(readxl)
library(magrittr)

#dataframe is read from Excel file 
df <- read_excel('data_RT.xlsx')

df <- df[c(1, 2, 4, 6, 8)]


df %>%
  group_by(ConditionID) %>%
  get_summary_stats(RT, type = "mean_sd") 

#detection of outliers using the rstatix package

outliers <- df %>%
  group_by(ConditionID) %>%
  identify_outliers(RT)

#normality assumption using rstatix package

normality <- df %>%
  group_by(ConditionID) %>%
  shapiro_test(RT)

#our sample size (amount of measurements) is above 50, the normal QQ plot needs to
#is preferred, since the Shapiro-Wilk test is sensitive to minor deviations at larger sample sizes

ggqqplot(df, "RT", facet.by = "ConditionID")

#the ANOVA test
res.aov <- anova_test(data = df, dv = RT, wid = Pid, within = ConditionID)
get_anova_table(res.aov)

#post-hoc-tests

pwc <- dfm %>%
  pairwise_t_test(
    reaction_times ~ condition, paired = TRUE,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
  )
pwc
```

Idk what to do. If you want me to send the Excel sheet, I can email it to you.

Comment: It would really help if you added some data in the post. Use `dput` (or any of the other methods mentioned in this [guide](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html). A few lines of data should suffice to reproduce the error. 

Your example also contains lot's of code that is seemingly unrelated - plotting and and pruning.  It would help the clarity if you'd just include the code relevant to reproduce the error.